# Show that an integral domain with elements integral over $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $A$ be an integral domain which contains the field of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose that every element $a\in A$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. Prove that $A$ is a field.

Comment: More is true in general: if $\;A\subset B\;$ are ID such that $\;B\;$ is integral over $\;A\;$ , then $\;B\;$ is a field iff $\;A\;$ is.

Comment: Oh ok, that's interesting. So this has shown that $B$ is a field if $A$ is (where my example is $A=B$ and $\mathbb{Q}=A$ - confusingly). How would I show that other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a\ne0$, then $a^n+b_{n-1}a^{n-1}+\dots+b_1a+b_0=0$ for some $b_0,\dots,b_{n-1}\in\mathbb{Q}$, with $n\ge1$ and $b_0\ne0$ (prove it). Then
$$
a(a^{n-1}+b_{n-1}a^{n-2}+\dots+b_1)=-b_0
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: I think so.

Ok, so $b_{0}\neq0$ because $a\neq0$ and since $A$ is an integral domain, there are no zero divisors.

Since $b_{0}\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$, $b_{0}^{-1}\in\mathbb{Q}$. Now, $$1=a(a^{n-1}+b_{n-1}a^{n-2}+\ldots+b_{1})(-b_{0}^{-1}).$$ Hence every $a\in A$ has an inverse and so $A$ is a field.

Comment: @PercyF2519 Right: if we find a polynomial relation where $b_0=0$, we can cancel $a$ and find one with lower degree, so by recursion we end up with one that satisfies our requirement. The rest is good. One could also use the minimal polynomial and use the fact it is irreducible, but this is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Let $0\neq x\in A$. We will be done if we show that there exists $y\in A$ such that $xy=1$. By hypothesis, there exists $p\in \Bbb Q [X]$ such that $p(x)=0$. Without loss of generality, assume $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $x$. It has a nonzero constant term, hence we can subtract it over and multiply by the negative of the inverse. On the left-hand side, we now have an $x$ in common with all of the terms, so we may factor it out. What remains is the inverse of $x$.